# Why does Word 2010 hang with a lot of I/O events?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

Word 2010 hangs regularly on the following:

```
16:20:48,8337135    WINWORD.EXE 5128    RegQueryKey HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Word    SUCCESS Query: HandleTags, HandleTags: 0x0
16:20:48,8337863    WINWORD.EXE 5128    RegOpenKey  HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Word\Coauthoring    NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read/Write
```

The key `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Word\Coauthoring` does not exist, but this is a clean Office installation.

(this is repeated 500,000 times in a couple of minutes).

I have to kill Word (and lose my work) to continue.
Any suggestions how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you create the Coauthoring registry path?

Also, what sort of access does your user account have to that registry path?
 - Right click on the key furthest along that path and select permissions. Your account should have a check in Full Control.

Comment: I've created the key and I have full permissions. Will wait to see if that solves the problem

Answer (score 3):

Try the [Office repair](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint-help/repair-or-remove-office-2010-HA010357402.aspx#_Toc269981340) features:

> Repair your Office 2010 programs by doing the following:
>
> 1. Click Start, then click Control Panel.
> 2. Click Programs and Features.
> 3. Click the Office 2010 program that you want to repair, then click Change.
> 4. Click Repair, then click Continue.
>
> You might need to restart your computer after the repair is complete.